# Pushsharp connection failure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, apple-push-notifications, pushsharp

So I am using push sharp inside of my ASP.NET mvc application and I keep getting a connection failure error.  I installed the NUGET package for push sharp so I don't have access to the source code. It took me a while to realize I was getting this error since I wasn't running in debug for a while.  First off here is the error code I get.

> An unhandled exception of type PushSharp.Apple.ConnectionFailureException occurred in PushShart.Apple.DLL
>
> Additional Information: Maximum number of attempts (3) to connect to gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 was reached!

This is the code I am using for the push notificaitons.  Its pretty simple.

```
public int samplePush()
    {
        var push = new PushBroker();
        var appleCert = File.ReadAllBytes(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Certificates1.p12"));
        var settings = new ApplePushChannelSettings(false, appleCert, "1111");
        push.RegisterAppleService(settings);
        push.QueueNotification(new AppleNotification()
            .ForDeviceToken("c49e457bc041dead313f43684a42a0acdc8d4393b229db08e2873849a8a2db22")
            .WithAlert("Test push notification")
            .WithSound("default")
            .WithBadge(7));
        push.OnNotificationFailed += push_OnNotificationFailed;
        push.StopAllServices();
        return 200;
    }
```

I have tried a number of things, first I used multiple certificates including the pem file but none of them give me any errors as far as invalid certificates go.

I also manually opened up port 2195 to allow all connections, I also tried this from multiple connections one of them being my work connection which has worked for push notifications in the past.  I am at a loss here of what could be causing this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final part of it came down to a certificate error.  Apparently going to an adhoc copy required a new certificate.